# MIPS Program not Printing Primes Correctly

Tags: mips

I have an assignment that requires us to write two functions in MIPS: One that determines if a number is prime or not, and another that finds all the primes between 3 and 102 inclusive and prints them out. Obviously, the second one uses the first; this is meant to be an exercise in jumping and branching. The source code we are given already cleans up the stack and registers, etc., for us, and provides a function to print the number in $a0, so all we need to do is the aforementioned functions. No matter what I do, my program will always just print "1" and exit, even though it should be looping over many numbers. I feel like the mistake I have made is simple, like not loading anything into a register that needs it or overlooking something similarly simple, but I'm still new to MIPS and debugging assembly code is honestly a nightmare. Here are the two functions I've written:

Here's the one for checking if a number is prime:

```
        ori     $s0,$a0,0               #make a copy of the argument
        ori     $t0,$s0,0               #using temp registers is good
        ori     $s1,$s0,0               #make another copy to use as the loop-end check
        li      $t2,2                   #use 2 as the divisor, makes it easier to check
        li      $v0,0                   #using "not prime" as the base case
prime_test:
        slt     $t1,$t2,$s1             #check if we're above the ceiling
        beq     $t1,$zero,found_prime
        div     $t0,$t2                 #check if number is divisible by 2
        mfhi    $t3                     #get remainder from hi
        beq     $t3,$zero,not_prime     #if hi=0, it's not a prime
        addi    $t2,$t2,1
        j       prime_test
not_prime:
        add     $v0,$zero,$zero         #return false (0) if not prime
found_prime:
        jal     print_number            #if it's prime, print it
```

And here's the one for looping and checking from 3 to 102:

```
        li      $t0,102         #upper boundary
        li      $a0,3           #lower boundary
prime_loop:
        slt     $t5,$a0,$t0
        beq     $t5,$zero,found_all_primes
        jal     is_prime
        slt     $t2,$zero,$a0
        bne     $t2,$zero,prime_detected

prime_detected:
        addi    $a0,$a0,1       #increment the counter
        j       prime_loop

found_all_primes:
```

Honestly, I think the error is probably in the function that loops; I'm pretty sure my logic for testing if a number is prime is sound, but I could have easily overlooked something. Again, don't worry about it looking like registers aren't being restored properly, that's all taken care of already.

Comment: There's no way for us to verify from the code that you've posted that `is_prime` actually preserves `$t0` (which your `prime_loop` depends on). Also, `bne     $t2,$zero,prime_detected` is pointless. The next instruction that will be executed is `addi    $a0,$a0,1` regardless of whether the branch is taken or not.

Comment: @Michael Thanks a lot for pointing that out, you're absolutely right. I completely forgot that I was trashing the temp registers by using the same ones between the functions. I've changed it so they all use different registers. So now it prints out 3 and immediately quits, which is progress. I still can't figure out what's wrong with my loop, though, although you're certainly right about the bne with prime_detected being superfluous.

Comment: Actually, never mind--I have figured out what is causing the counter to be erroneously updated. This can be closed.